# How to transfer data between two method through thymeleaf in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am creating a reset password page and in that I have multiple pages. In one page I take email from the user and pass that value to another method using model.addAttribute(), I am able to access access the data on the on other method in controller after submot action it is showing null;

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/verify")
    public String forgetPass(Model model,@ModelAttribute("login") Login login){
        if(otpServices.verify(login)){
            String newpass="";
            String email=login.getEmail();
            model.addAttribute("email",email);
            model.addAttribute("pass",newpass);
            return "NewPass";
        }else {
            return "ForgetPass";
        }
    }
    @PostMapping("/newpass")
    public String newPass(@ModelAttribute("email") String email, @ModelAttribute("pass") String pass ){
        userServices.updatePass(email,pass);
        return "Home";
    }
```

View(Thymeleaf)

```
<form th:action="@{/newpass}" method="post" >
                <h2 class="text-center">New Password</h2>
                <div class="alert alert-success text-center" th:text="${email}">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Create new password" required th:field="*{pass}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm your password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control button" type="submit" name="change-password" value="Change">
                </div>
            </form>
```

I also tried using objects and putting values in them and manually accessing data with model.getAttribute but every time the value comes out to be null;
I will appreciate any help as I am new to it;

Comment: You're trying to get the properties in newPass that were set in forgetPass?

Comment: yes, when I try to access the property it is giving null;

Comment: I've added an answer. What you're trying to do isn't possible. Model attributes disappear after the request. There only intended to pass data to the view/Thymeleaf for that single request. They don't persist beyond that. See my answer for alternate solutions.

Comment: What solution did you end up choosing?

Comment: So I used HttpSession to add an attribute, and then I was able to access the required data throughout the session. It is a much better approach, as I am able to access the required data such as email and username anytime. 
Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: No problem. If my answer solved your problem it would be appreciated if you mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model attributes only live for one request**

What you are trying to do is not possible. The model attributes only live for the life of a single request. When the post to /verify is complete all of the model attributes are gone. The last place to access them is in the view/Thymeleaf page. If you want to persist state beyond a single request you can place data into the users session or use "flash attributes" which do the same thing under the hood.

**Design considerations**

I think you should really be doing all of this logic in one method. If the verification fails then return one response then if it succeeds return something else. Having one method to save the email and password state and then another to actually persist it seems redundant. I'd recommend you put the verification inside the /newPass method.

Forgot password should probably be its own method. /forgot-password can take an email address and send an email token. The token link in the email takes users to a form where they post to /new-password where that method verifies if the email is unique and if not saves it.